# Ubuntu 18.04.2 Ethernet Bonding

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-bonding

This question is quite unique and different from other guides and documentations out there.

I don't see any point in bonding two NICs that are connected to the same source because if the source goes down, then bond0 will be rendered useless.

What I'm doing is, I'm trying to bond two NICs with each one having a different source (ISP) so it's obvious that each one of them will have a different IP address, different gateway etc.

My question is: following almost "every guide" on the internet shows that bond0 needs to be static and i need to set an IP address for it as well as a gateway. How on earth am I supposed to set a static IP address with a static gateway FOR TWO DIFFERENT SOURCEs?

Can someone please explain this?

let's say NIC1 have:
IP_ADDRESS=192.168.1.3
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1

NIC2 have:
IP_ADDRESS=192.168.2.14
GATEWAY=192.168.2.1

BOND0 should be static based on what?
What am I supposed to write in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Just a small note - 18.04 is not using `etc/network/interfaces` you need to use netplan.

Comment: :# hey! thanks for the note, but `/etc/network/interfaces` does exist and if i do `sudo service networking restart` it does reread the file content and applies them. if i'm wrong please correct me. lsb_release -d shows "Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"